# How Can I send full content body field by simplenews_content_selection?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, emails

I use the drupal 7 and [simple news content selection](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection) module for simplenews.

When select an existing content for send by simplenews only the title of its content add to simplenews sent mail.

I want to send whole content (the full body field) of selected content by simplenews.have any idea?

thanks before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution.

In content type **manage display** setting , for `simplenews content selection` view mode the `body` field must be visible .